# Prevent simultaneously click on UIButtons

Tags: ios

Use `btn.userInteractionEnabled` and `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]` not works, but set `btn.exclusiveTouch=YES` works.

Anyone tell me why?

## EDIT:

I have two buttons(**btn1** and **btn2**), and I don't want them to be triggered when they are clicked simultaneously.

Firstly, I wrote `btn2.userInteractionEnabled=NO` in the event handler of **btn1**, and the same in **btn2** event handler. But it doesn't work. **btn2** still triggered when its userInteractionEnabled is set to NO.

Then I changed userInteractionEnabled to beginIgnoringInteractionEvents, but still doesn't work.

At last, I found **exclusiveTouch**, and it seems to work all the time.

My question is why `userInteractionEnabled` and `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents` doesn't work immediately.

Comment: Provide more context, please. Specify at least what is an expected behavior and what you get instead.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622453-exclusivetouch?language=objc) of `exclusiveTouch` : **Setting this property to YES causes the receiver to block the delivery of touch events to other views in the same window. The default value of this property is NO.**

Comment: @FyodorVolchyok updated

Comment: @NiravD I know it, but why setting btn's userInteractionEnabled directly doesn't work? They are on main thread. 

Does UIKit have a async method to record which btns will be triggered before the event handler is really triggered.

Comment: @Tepmnthar, I tested, the `btn.userInteractionEnabled = false`, then the btn will not be able to click okay?

Comment: @Tepmnthar line `btn2.userInteractionEnabled=NO` is executed in your button1 action before that button2 action is also fired. You can check by putting break point in second function also.

Comment: Yes, it was executed before I enter btn2 action because I have a breakpoint in btn2 action, and it shows `btn2.userInteractionEnabled=NO`. It can prevent calling btn2 action a moments later, but it doesn't work when you click btn1 and btn2 at the same time(btn1 is clicked a bit earlier). @NiravD

Comment: @Tepmnthar Don't you think that the exactly i have mentioned in my previous comment.